# How to restrict a user to access objects of only one schema in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to restrict a user to only one schema and to only Select privilege in that schema in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You command is [Grant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)

Comment: But how to compose to restrict it to one schema only

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A combination of DENYs and a GRANT.  For example:

```
DENY SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [user_name]
DENY SELECT ON schema::[other_schema] TO [user_name]
GRANT SELECT ON schema::[safe_schema] TO [user_name]
```

Comment: User is still able to create tables on that schema !!

Comment: @DheerajKumar - rather than try to address your issue in the comment section of an answer that's over 11 years old(!!), feel free to post a new question with your setup, what your requirements/expectations are, and what is actually happening.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem, so no issues actually:)