# how to enable a user to access only one database from user having sysadmin server role

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the sql server 2008, i have 10 users, out of which 1 user aem has sysadmin access in server roles of sql authentication.

I want the remaining 9 users to access their corresponding databases and restrict access on other databases.

After logging from user aem which has sysadmin access in server roles.
I have changed the server roles of all 9 users to sysadmin, but it can open all databases, i tried changing in user mapping to particular database and default_schema to select all checkboxes and changed default database from master to particular database.

When i login from normal user, it can open the particular database, but only system tables are visisble.

I checked with below links,

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283984/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-access-objects-of-only-one-schema-in-sql-server-2008) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085700/restrict-sql-server-login-access-to-only-one-database)

I tried changing again and again in the options from security -> logins to restrict the user on particular database.I dont get the correct solution.

Thanks

Comment: Sysadmin role members have full permissions over the SQL instance and all databases.  You cannot limit sysadmin permissions.  If certain users need privileged access to only certain databases, consider adding then to the db_owner role instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am lost after your third paragraph.

I am assuming you need DB_OWNER permissions on the relevant user.

Please clear up your question.

Comment: @Greensmith, Thank you